# Similar Application to GemBox for word

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I'm using GemBox for my project now. Currently my module requires only excel which is why I've tried and really like using this application. Talk to my PM about the possibility of purchasing it but they wanted something similar that might work for word documents as well as just excel so that others might use it as it is more common for word documents to be generated.

Answer (score 3):

These product have both Excel and Word component.

SoftArtisans OfficeWriter
http://www.softartisans.com/

aspose cells and word
http://www.aspose.com/

office.Net
http://www.independentsoft.de/office/index.html

Answer (score 2):

GemBox also has both Excel and Word component:

- [GemBox.Spreadsheet for Excel in .NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet)
- [GemBox.Document for Word in .NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked both with GemBox and Aspose (in particular using Aspose with Word and PDF) and personally i prefer this second one.

In addition Aspose let you manipulate a lot of file format (pdf, word, excell, power point, one note, eml, msg.. and so on), depending on which license you required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Docentric Toolkit](http://www.docentric.com/). It uses Word template documents and fills them with data from any source which can be read by .NET. Templates can even be prepared/modified by end users, is they are permitted to do so.